# jquery chrome Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I've just started getting the following error in all the pages on my website. This looks like some low level chrome api stuff but I'm not sure why it's suddenly showing it's ugly head?

> Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>   at topLevelDomainOf (chrome-extension://bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei/cfg.js:1:2012)
>   at chrome-extension://bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei/content2.js:1:11080
>   at null. (chrome-extension://bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei/content2.js:1:11271)
>   at chrome-extension://bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei/ci.content.pack.js:1:2448
>   at Function.propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)
>   at Event.dispatchToListener (event_bindings:382:22)
>   at Event.dispatch_ (event_bindings:367:27)
>   at Event.dispatch (event_bindings:388:17)
>   at messaging:187:31
>   at Function.propertyNames.forEach.target.(anonymous function) (extensions::SafeBuiltins:19:14)

Comment: try to disable the chrome extension `keeper`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error depends by one chrome extension. Because in the stack trace there is a path with schema `chrome-extension://`.

Some extension, generally, inject a javascript in every page: if this javascript contains some error, you can view it in console.

In your case the extension `bfogiafebfohielmmehodmfbbebbbpei` is Keeper (you can see it with a simple search on google of this code).

More info about extensions management https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443